# How to make autocommit false in nodejs for db2?

Tags: node.js, db2

In nodejs for db2, i want to make the autocommit  false for performing batch operation so that i can commit and rollback. I there anyfunction for making autocommit false, else how can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, autocommit is off for all clients except when working with the CLI program. Thus, you do not need to set **autocommit** to off.

With the Node SDK you would use the transaction-related commands like BeginTransaction and [CommitTransaction](https://github.com/ibmdb/node-ibm_db/blob/master/APIDocumentation.md#commitTransactionSyncApi) to control transaction boundaries. The linked API command has a sample.

Comment: Yes i tried like this only but without using the commitTransaction the transaction is committed. so i cant rollback the transaction.

Comment: Post your code if it does not work. Are you opening and closing a connection? Same as commit.

Comment: thanks...now its working...i didn't close the connection. so it is automatically commiting